# What would make it possible to bind to a property that does not exists (TreeViewItem only ?)

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, treeview, styles

In my xaml I have something that looks like:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpandedOverridedInModelView, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This code works perfectly.

My TreeView is bound to a ModelView hierarchy (MVVM) that wrap my DataLayer hierarchy. A Hierarchy wrapper over another hierarchy. My bounded ModelView hierarchy add few properties like (IsSelected and IsExpandedOverridedInModelView). This code mainly does define a binding between the TreeView.IsExpanded property and my ModelView hierarchy property: "IsExpandedOverridedInModelView".

But there is something I haven't been able to figured out...

Everybody know that a TreeViewItem class does not have a property called "IsExpandedOverridedInModelView". This property if part of my underlying object (the object in my ModelView behind the TreeViewItem). I have 2 related questions:

- What would make that declaration possible ? What is the twist that enable that behavior ?
- How to declare that in order to remove the ~"warning" saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'IsExpandedOverridedInModelView'" (how to declare that in a clean manner) ?

I thought that TreeViewItem would derive from DynamicObject but it is not the case.

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying that you want to bind to something that does not exist?  Or are you saying that `IsExpanded` *does* exist, but on a different object, and you need to be able to bind it correctly?

Comment: Hi Dan, Sorry for not being enough clear, I just realized that I did not express my thought enough clearly. I changed the name of a variable and added more explanation that I hope will clarify the idea behind my question. Thanks for you feed back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeViewItem` *has* an [`IsExpanded` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isexpanded.aspx). Any warnings that tell you otherwise are the result of some IDE crap. And the binding refers to the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) which may or may not have such a property, which is only evaluated at runtime unless you use a designer (again, warnings from that are just IDE crap).

Comment: Hello H.B.Thanks for your answer. Seeing your answer show me that my question was not clear enough. I modified my code from "IsExpanded" to "IsExpandedOverridedInModelView". It should clarify my thought. Sorry for not being enough clear.

Comment: @EricOuellet: As i said, the property in the binding refers to the `DataContext` and not the `TreeViewItem`. If you don't know what the `DataContext` is read the docs i linked to in my answer.

Comment: Hi H.B., I think I know what is a DataContext. But in this case I define a style that refer to a hierarchy TreeViewItem. Using DataType should impose by itself the DataContext to this class or any derived class. In other words, the DataContext here is implicit by the declaration itself. TreeViewDataItem is the DataContext. But knowing that, how does  it take the property defined in my ViewModel ?

Comment: @EricOuellet: I have no idea what you are talking about, if you have a binding without source it **binds to the property on the DataContext**, in any `ItemsControl` the DataContext of the item containers will be the ViewModels (or rather the data item in the `ItemsSource` collection which usually is a VM).

Comment: @HB, Yes and no. You are right, if the binding has no source, it will default to the DataContext (usually the view model). But there is no DataContext per Hierachical DataItem. As you said, the DataContext is per control. I was wrong there in my explanation (in fact it was an image, a way to explain, but it was not appropriate from me). To me, there is virtual DataContext coming from the control but behavior could not be attached to it, only to its childs. DataType serves as kind of virtual DataContext or at least it should offer same advantages as d:DataContext.

Comment: @EricOuellet: I still don't have a clue what you are trying to say. Of course the is a `DataContext` in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, it's inherited from the `TreeViewitem`.